# Is that possible to use != in query string?

Tags: list, sharepoint, filter, query-string

I am filtering sharepoint list using query string for some reson i need to check condition like FieldValue!=Red is that possible to achive?

Or still its limitation?

.aspx?FilterName=EYHealthIndicator&FilterMultiValue=Red;Yellow&&FilterField2=ContentType&**FilterValue2!=Task**

Comment: @DarrenDavies : no no in query string i am asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't AFAIK.

The workaround MAY be to create a calculated column and then filter on that.

E.g. create a column called "Not-Red" with formula

=IF([YOUR_COLUMN_NAME]="Red","False","True")

Then filter

?FilterField1=Not-Red&FilterValue2=True

Comment: I am creating list definition and its done already, i cant edit list definiton now. Actucally for sharepoint where to learn about the querystring filter related stuff?

Answer (score 2):

You could use Sharepoint Designer to filter a new, dedicated view of that list. You need:
 1) a queryString parameter like ?FilteredNotValue!=Red
 2) Add filter in designer , operator = "Not Equal" , value = new parameter --> Name param = FilteredNotValue! --> Parameter Source = QueryString.
Ending the name of the param with "!" is a trick but it seems could do the work.

Comment: i cant use deigner its a custom code based application, so i have line there if i click it it has to pass with this filter parameter.

Comment: You can keep using your parameter name ( FilterValue2! ) and using SP Designer only to define a "Not equal" filter on your View ( Task%20Summary.aspx )