# What's a RESTful way to query with filters?

Tags: rest, api-design

Say my application is managing objects called workload, with the following fields. I want to expose a REST interface for user to query workloads by labels.

```
"Workload": {"id":"test1", "labels":["A", "B", "C"]}
"Workload": {"id":"test2", "labels":["A", "C", "D"]}
"Workload": {"id":"test3", "labels":["A", "B", "D"]}
```

**Question**: How do I design the REST endpoint so that it would supports query workload by *multiple* labels as filter?

**Sample Query 1**: I want to `GET` all the workloads with both "A" and "B".

I'm thinking something like `GET` as verb, `workloads` as endpoint, then use a `{"labels": ["A", "B"]}` as request body. But this does not seem like a RESTful way to do things

Alternatively, I can do `GET /labels/{label-id}/workloads` but this would only work with one label per time.

<s>**Sample Query 2**: I want to `GET` all the workloads with label "A" or "B" but no "C"</s>

No clue how to do this sort of rest api at all, other than ask user to query by A, B, C separately then do proper set operations themselves?

The second query is [tracked as another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39670733/whats-a-restful-way-to-query-with-logic-operation)

Comment: I don't think that there is anything wrong with query parameters. Is there any reason you want to avoid them?

Comment: I was having doubt whether I want to/can repeat query parameters. As I am coding my application in `golang`, and I am using a [third party library`httprouter`](https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter) to help me automatically parse the parameter, which currently only supports single query parameters... things like `workload/:workload_id/labels/:label_id`

Answer (score 1):

GET verb not takes request body. You should do something like 'workload /labels/A, B, C '. 
You then get A,B, C in request query. Make an array with comma separated from request query and find records.

Comment: 1. Can I use [comma in URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198606/can-i-use-commas-in-a-url). 2. How to do query like "give me workloads with label 'A' or 'B' but no 'C' " in comma separated list?

Comment: @cookieisaac Comma in URL depends on server side routing implementation, e.g. by node.js express you can have, by IIS there can be problems. You need to test it first.

Answer (score 1):

Use query parameters, [its fine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24728298/1083707) to [repeat them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2602127/1083707).

```
GET /workloads?label=A&label=B&label=C
```

For simple cases you could also`or` and `not` the terms like this.

```
GET /workloads?or_label=A&or_label=B&label_not=C
```

Comment: This looks good enough for my situation. Just wondering if I can go crazy and do something like `GET /workloads?(label=A||label=B)&label!=C`? Or is there anyway I can do some basic logic operations like '(A or B) not C'

Comment: You might try posting it as a new question. I can't think of an obvious solution. Perhaps you need another (set of) resource(s) to define your query and then get the results with `GET /queries/{id}/workloads`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10582066/is-that-possible-to-use-in-query-string

Comment: @cookieisaac There were many previous questions about URI and logical operators, maybe you should check those. e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25749060/boolean-logic-in-restful-filtering-and-queries

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of options the only constraint here, that they should contain `A` and `B`. So for example

- `/workloads/?label=["A","B"]`
- `/workloads/?label[]=A&label[]=B` - aka. [query string array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243051/how-to-pass-an-array-within-a-query-string)
- `/workloads/by/label/A+B/`
- `/label/A+B/workloads/`

There are existing URI query conventions as well, for example Microsoft Odata. http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/odata-v4.0-part2-url-conventions.html I am not familiar with OData, but according to the docs you should use something like `/WorkloadsByLabels(labels=@c)?@c=["A","B"]` if you want to follow their approach. Afaik. there is no standard solution to describe complex URI filters.

Comment: It looks like a legit solution, but I've never seen any REST api designed that way...Are these conventional for RESTful endpoints or mostly for URI? I was thinking along the lines like say, [IBM Bluemix REST API](http://ccsapi-doc.mybluemix.net/), but they don't seem to support complex query...

Comment: @cookieisaac If you are looking for a standard solution, then you should check URI templates https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6570 . It defines a list type, which is added to the URI as items separated with comma. Sadly not every server supports comma in URI, e.g. IIS has problems with it. Afaik the plus character is used mostly to separate search keywords and not to separate list items, so it is just a tip, not a convention as far as I know. On the other hand URI templates is a standard, so you can separate the ids with comma if your server supports that. The query string array is standard too.