# How to express != in URLs

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, url

I wrote the following ajax call to fetch data using the nb (number of document view) parameter:

```
if ($("#fetch").hasClass("active")) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "ServletAjaxController",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: "c=" + controller + "&nb=300",
    success: onSuccess,
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
  });
}
```

Now I want to do the same thing but expressing nb != 300 instead of the equal expression. Any IDEAs?

Comment: That depends on how the backend code interprets the `nb` values you send.

Comment: That would depend on the api. What you are describing is just `query parameters` and has nothing to do with the actual data query (despite its name).

Comment: still be the same, all you have to do is to set a condition in your backend and pass an extra parameter that will tell the backend when to do !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is that possible to use != in query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10582066/is-that-possible-to-use-in-query-string)

Comment: Unless you mean something like an OData query, that's not how query options work.  They are key/value pairs, exactly like you already have.  `!=` would have no meaning.  You'd instead include a parameter of some other name and use that logic in your back-end code.